# Как обратиться к функции в ViewController из AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

Что нужно прописать в applicationDidBecomeActive (AppDelegate) чтобы обраться к функции размещенной в ViewController.m?

Comment: `self.reference.method;` где reference это референс к контроллеру, и  method это метод который надо вызывать

Comment: в Info.plist или еще куда-то добавлять какую-нибудь настройку нужно?

Comment: нужно каким то образом создать референс к нужному контроллеру в appdelegate. но в целом это плохая практика, лучше будет чтоб контроллер подписался на уведомление и не трогал appdelegate вообще

Answer (score 0):

Создайте поле в AppDelegate.h:

```
@property UIViewController* vc;
```

AppDelegate.m:

// Получение экземпляра AppDelegate

```
+ (AppDelegate *)getInstance
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

При создании ViewController обратитесь к экземпляру AppDelegate и присвойте значение переменной:

ViewController.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [AppDelegate getInstance].vc = self;
}
-(void)yourMethod {

}
```

При необходимости обратитесь к функции из AppDelegate.m:

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    if (self.vc)
    {
        [vc yourMethod];
    }
}
```

---

Добавлю что это не идеальный способ, но вполне рабочий.
Альтернатива - подписка на нотификации и отправка нотификации.
Подписка:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:
self selector:@selector(showEventNotification:) 
name:@"yourMethod" object:nil];
```

Обработка:

```
- (void)yourMethod:(NSNotification *)notification
{

}
```

Отправка:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"yourMethod" 
object:notification.userInfo];
```

Удаление подписки:

```
    - (void)dealloc {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
removeObserver:yourMethod object:nil];
    }
```